# How to Regex.Replace in Word without destroy the format?

Tags: c#, regex, replace, ms-word

I am trying to search/replace in a Word document. However, the font format (and not only) like bold/font family/colors etc is totally disappeared after the replace. Here is a sample of my code (it replaces "a1" with a greek character, if greek letters follow):

```
Word.Selection selection = this.Application.Selection;
selection.Range.Text = Regex.Replace(selection.Range.Text, @"(a1)\p{IsGreek}+", "ά");
```

Is there a straightforward way to do that?

I also tried a more complicated one:

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(selection.Range.Text, @"(a1)\p{IsGreek}+", RegexOptions.Multiline);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    object start = match.Groups[1].Index;// -counter * (match.Groups[1].Length - 1);
    object end = (int)start + match.Groups[1].Length;
    Word.range l_rng = doc.Range(ref start, ref end);
    l_rng.Text = "ά";
}
```

This approach keeps the format but in case of very large documents, `start` and `end` indexes are messed up after a while. Probably because of page breaks or other characters, but I can not figure out yet.

Comment: Doesn't a normal Search & Replace do the trick?

Comment: No, I need to search using a regular expression pattern.

Comment: You can do a regex search in the Search&Replace dialog box by clicking on 'Use wildcards', and I believe you can use `[Α-ϖ]` to match greek characters in the dialog box (those are the first and last greek characters).

Comment: Yes, you are right. BUT... I want to keep the character that matches [Α-ω] in the replacement string. E.g.
`a1[Α-ω]` --> `ά[Α-ω]`

In the case of regex `\p{IsGreek}` is maintained in the output.

Comment: OK! I found the solution: find: `a1([Α-ω])`, replace: `a1\1`. Write the answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Oh, apparently, `Ά` is before `Α`, so I'll be using this in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple Search & Replace to do that, and since this feature doesn't touch the formatting at all, that might be the better solution. For instance, you can use this regex for Find, making sure to enable 'Use wildcards' (you click 'More >>' to get this feature visible in the dialog box):

```
a1([Ά-ω]@)
```

`[Ά-ω]` will match the greek characters (I'm pretty sure you have most, of not all greek characters in that character class, if not, I'm open to corrections) and `@` means one or more.

Then in the replace, you can put it back:

```
ά\1
```

`\1` will refer to the capture group of greek characters we matched earlier.

Input:

```
a1Άλφα
```

Output:

```
άΆλφα
```